# Windows Mobile - voice control + speech synthesis (text to speech)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I've got Windows Mobile 6.5 application and I need to add simple voice control (like "yes" and "no" commands recognition). I'd also like to add possibility of reading text displayed on LCD.

I'd appreciate any suggestions about possible solutions for such problem. Are there any free libraries with described functionalities?

Thanks for any help, MattheW

Answer (score 1):

Luckly there are also open source alternatives:
 - [espeak](http://www.efficasoft.com/download/eSpeak-1.29-wm.cab) for speech synthesis
 - PocketSphinx for speech recognition

Answer (score -1):

Windows Mobile supports [SAPI 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms897381.aspx), which supports command-based speech recognition and text-to-speech.

Comment: No, it actually doesn't.  Windows CE does but WinMo doesn't contain any of those pieces.  Even under CE, there are no voices included, so the "support" is more on paper than reality.

Comment: Then why does my WinMo phone have Voice Command, which does voice recognition and text to speech?

Comment: Downloaded a bunch of WinMo SDKs, and, sigh, apparently SAPI is NOT part of the SDK.  Never mind.

Comment: Voice Command is actually a separate, proprietary engine.  Unfortunately it has no API, and in fact it's a license violation to even try to use it from anotehr app.  I sincerely wish we did have voice reco/TTS under WinMo or even CE.